# Let $f$ a linear function in $(Mat_n(\mathbb{R}))^*$. Prove $f(E_{11})=...=f(E_{nn})$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ a linear function in $(Mat_n(\mathbb{R}))^*$. such that $f(AB)=f(BA)$ for all $A,B \in Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$. Let $\{E_{ij}: 1\leq i,j\leq n\}$ the canonical basis of $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$

Prove $f(E_{11})=...=f(E_{nn})$.

**Note:** $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of matrix of orden $n$

Note$_2$: $(Mat_n(\mathbb{R}))^*=\{f|f:Mat_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{K}\}$

I don't have a clear idea of how prove this. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: try to find matrices $A,B$ such that $AB=E_{ii},BA=E_{jj}$.

Comment: @Wojowu if i take $A=E_{ij}$ and $B=E_{ji}$ then$E_{ij}E_{ji}=E_{ii}$ and $E_{ji}E_{ij}=E_{jj}$ and how $f(E_{ij}E_{ji})=f(E_{ji}E_{ij})$ then we obtain the required. no?